# Vim pattern for replacing ftp links with local

Tags: vim, html, regex

## Question

I'm going to be sorting through a large mass of html files and replacing links to an ftp site with local links. I am using vim and I am trying to figure out a pattern to use with `%s/find/replace/g` that will match a string such as

```
href="ftp://some/directory/to/a/random.pdf"
```

and replace it with

```
href="local/directory/random.pdf"
```

essentially replacing everything except the file name itself. *There will be multiple ftp directories in a single html file so the pattern should be able to match any type of ftp link*. All of these ftp files will be going into the same local directory. Although most of the files are pdfs some are ptts and other random files.

**Are Vim's patterns able to match something like this, and if so what would that pattern look like?**

## Answer

**@akira** did a great job with the regex supplied in his answer. I went out on my own to find a way to put this into a reusable function and this is what I came up with:

(inside your vimrc) define a function that allows you to pass a string to replace the matched string

```
function SwitchFtp(local)
    execute ':%s,href="ftp://.*/\(.\+\)",href="'.a:local.'\1",g'
endfunction
```

*(optional)* assign this function to a command so that you don't have to use `call`

```
command -nargs=1 SwitchFtp call SwitchFtp(<f-args>)
```

This would then be called with something like

```
:SwitchFtp local/directory/
```

Comment: so, "replace everything from 'ftp://' up to the last '/'" ?

Comment: yes, without matching the filename itself if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:%s,href="ftp://.*/\(.\+\)",href="local/directory/\1",g
```

Comment: I updated the question with some clarification. There will not be a common directory on the ftp site, these files will be linked from multiple directories, hence the need for a pattern.

Comment: haha, that's amazing. Now to try to turn this thing into a function (help's appreciated, but the pattern is a good start). Thanks for the help! I'll have to look into how you did this later. Lots of stuff I haven't seen yet in it.

Answer (score 0):

To take

```
href="ftp://some/directory/to/a/random.pdf"
```

and replace it with

```
href="local/directory/to/a/random.pdf"
```

you want

```
:s#ftp://some/#local/#
```